# ZPL and mixing subsets

Tags: zpl

we have a new client that needs there bar code created with mixing subset C and A. We are using the ZPL language to print to a zebra printer and I've followed the Zebra programming guide but cant get the output I'm after. I need the bar code to read:

9931265099999891DJS12345670100060020

My code looks like this:

^BY3^BCN,200,Y,N,N
^FD>;9931265099999891>7DJS>512345670100060020^FS

and outputs this with some other characters that are not even ascii:
9931265099999891  S7M &* ...

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my own problem....

Thanks Magoo for taking time to look at my question...

When switching to subcode A you cannot just use the letters you want to display but must use a table (in the ZPL programming guide) that shows the characters that represent the characters that need to be displayed. I used this to get it to work, notice after changing to sub-code A (>7) you need duo characters to represent the characters you actually want displayed i.e.. 
    36 = D
    42 = J
    51 = S

```
^BY2^BCN,200,Y,N,Y,N
^FD>;9931265099999891>7364251>512345670100060020^FS
```

Hope my solution helped someone else
cheers all

Comment: Sorry guys just edited my own answer which is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using

^BCN,200,Y,N,N ^FD>;9931265099999891>6DJS1>52345670100060020^FS

Note that this switches to code `B` instead of `A`.

The final string of digits is an odd number of characters and it seemed to lop off the final character in code `C`. The string I constructed uses an even number of digits for each of the code-C sections and the remaining characters in code-B.

I could not get code-A to work at all, but I'm using an old printer (A300) which may not have the latest firmware.